# Export C dll methods to c# P/Invoke

Tags: c, dll, pinvoke, wrapper, dllimport

How to view method names with parameters list for a c dll?

I am trying to write C# wrapper for some C dlls from a third party application but on viewing c dll in dependency walker or PE explorer it just shows method names with some @@@@ symbols.

To write a dllImport wrapper I must know method name and parameters list but I do not have any idea how can view the method names and parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Realistically you need the documentation for the library. Without that you are going to struggle. Even if you can divine the function prototypes (parameters, calling convention etc.) you will struggle to know how to call those functions. For instance suppose you have this function:

```
void foo(int, int*);
```

Is the second parameter a pointer to a single value, or an array? You cannot tell from just the prototype.

Furthermore, the DLL will likely require constants, structs, and so on, none of which have meta-data in the DLL.

You can likely retrieve the prototypes with a demangler, i.e. http://demangler.com/ but realistically that won't be enough. Contact the vendor to obtain the documentation.

Comment: I need list of methods with parameters, how can that be viewed? I only have a dll but The demangler requires some different input. not sure how to use it? Is there any way to export c dll methods without any additional information?

Comment: You've got the mangled names from pe explorer. Or use dumpbin. Or dependency walker. And use the demangler linked from my answer. For instance. Why don't you contact the vendor?

Comment: I have licensed version of the product but they do not provide any API or additional info hence, I am trying to extend their API using P/Inoke

Comment: Well, I think you've got all the information now but I think you'll discover that what you are attempting is very hard. You'll almost certainly need to reverse engineer with a disassembler.